# How to change ComboBox list to appear above object programatically in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

How can I change the Combobox list to always appear above the ComboBox object using C# only (no XML)?
The property **DropDownStyle** doesn't seem to be available in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that `DropDownStyle` is only available for a [Windows Forms ComboBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not a [WPF ComboBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So, you need to go about this in a different way with WPF. Basically, WPF uses styles and templates to determine the visual aspects of a control.

For this particular problem, your going to need to edit the `Placement` property of the ComboBox's `Popup` control, which is part of its ControlTemplate.

Here is an example of how you could do this (put this in the code-behind):

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInitialized(e);

    // create a combo box
    var comboBox = new ComboBox
    {
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
        Width = 200
    };

    // add some items
    comboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Apple" });
    comboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Banana" });
    comboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = "Orange" });

    // add the combo box to your window
    AddChild(comboBox);

    // apply the control template
    comboBox.ApplyTemplate();

    // obtain the popup (which is named "PART_Popup") from the control template
    var controlTemplate = comboBox.Template;
    var popup = (Popup)controlTemplate.FindName("PART_Popup", comboBox);

    // set the placement of the popup
    if (popup != null) popup.Placement = PlacementMode.Top;
}
```

Final point: How did I know that there was a Popup called "PART_Popup"? There are a couple ways:

1. You can use Visual Studio designer to actually generate a copy of the standard control template for any built-in control. Specifically, place a control (e.g., a ComboBox) in your window, go to Document Outline, right click the ComboBox, and select "Edit Template...".
2. You can use the [Snoop utility](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to actually see the "visual tree" of controls/graphics in your window.